# How to save a recorded audio with reverb effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording

I am using **theamazingaudioengine** for recording, playing and adding effects like reverb for an iOS app. I can record, play the recorded audio along with the reverb effect. But I am unable to save audio file with the reverb effect to the gallery. Can any one please help me with this.

I am saving the recorded audio like this.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSArray *documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[documentsFolders objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.aiff"];

[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:path] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    /*notify of completion*/

    NSLog(@"AssetURL: %@",assetURL);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

    if (!error) {
        //video saved

        [[self appDelegate] showAlertWithTitle:@"Audio Saved" message:@""];

    }
    else{

        [[self appDelegate] showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.domain];

    }

}];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the code to show how you are currently saving the file albeit without the effect?

Comment: I have shared that in the question itself. I have edited my question to share that.

Comment: Check out my answer, that's how you should save edited audio.

Answer (score -1):

The `AEAudioFileWriter` class allows you to easily write to any audio file format supported by the system.

To use it, instantiate it using `initWithAudioDescription:` , passing in the audio format you wish to use. Then, begin the operation by calling `beginWritingToFileAtPath:fileType:error:` , passing in the path to the file you'd like to record to, and the file type to use. Common file types include `kAudioFileAIFFType`, `kAudioFileWAVEType`, `kAudioFileM4AType` (using AAC audio encoding), and `kAudioFileCAFType`.

Once the write operation has started, you use the C functions `AEAudioFileWriterAddAudio` and `AEAudioFileWriterAddAudioSynchronously` to write audio to the file. Note that you should only use `AEAudioFileWriterAddAudio` when writing audio from the Core Audio thread, as this is done asynchronously in a way that does not hold up the thread.

When you are finished, call `finishWriting` to close the file.

[More information...](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/interface_a_e_audio_file_writer.html)

Comment: Hi John! Thank you so much for the quick answer. Could you please share the code if you have on AEAudioFileWriter. I have gone through it but I couldn't get any example code.

Comment: @Woodstock can u please share the sample code for AEAudioFileWriter. I don't know how to use AEAudioFileWriterAddAudio and AEAudioFileWriterAddAudioSynchronously method

Comment: @Woodstock Did you found some sample code for now ?